# How to get php equivalent code for node js while integrating splash payments

Tags: php, node.js, rest

I am working on node js app. For splash payments they have given APIs in php only. So is there any way I can convert php code to node.js code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok so I had no idea what splash payments where so I took a brief look.
Are you sure there is a need to convert the php code you have to javascript?

I see splashpayments has a REST API which can be called directly from node.js without having to deal with a single line of PHP as REST is Language Agnostic.

> The REST APIs provide programmatic access to read, update and delete
>   data. Create new merchants, transactions and more. The responses are
>   returned in any format (XML, SOAP, JSON, FORM encoding) desired by the
>   client.

https://portal.splashpayments.com/docs/api